# Matlab - How to create logical array matrix without looping

Tags: matlab

I want to do something like the following:

```
Y = [1; 2; 3];
X = repmat(1:10, 3, 1);
for i=1:3
    X(i,:) = X(i,:) == Y(i);
end
```

So I end up with

```
X =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Is there a way to do this without looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start from `1:10` vector, using [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Y = [1; 2; 3];
X = bsxfun(@eq, Y, 1:10);
```

Otherwise with [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
Y = [1; 2; 3];
X = repmat(1:10, 3, 1);
X = repmat(Y, 1, size(X,2)) == X;
```

(Or [ones](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) as suggested by **leo**.)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be

```
Y = [1; 2; 3];
X = repmat(1:10, 3, 1);
Z = X == (Y * ones(1, 10)) ;
```

But I am not sure this is faster. It does not use a loop, though :)

EDIT : you could use a repmat instead of the * ones(1, 10)